# C- Multiple Definitions and Undefined References with SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I have googled solutions to my error, but it never seems to solve my problem. I'm not sure where the issue is because the #includes seem to check out. Thank you for your help.

Error:

```
gcc test.c -c -o test.o
gcc test.c -c -o Button.o
gcc -o test test.o Button.o -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -Wl,-subsystem
,windows
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `SDL_main'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x152): multiple definition of `init'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x152): first defined here
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x1c3): multiple definition of `load_image'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x1c3): first defined here
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x252): multiple definition of `apply_surface'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x252): first defined here
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Button_size'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `Button_constr'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `Button_handleEvents'
test.o:test.c:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `Button_show'
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Button_size'
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `Button_constr'
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `Button_handleEvents'
Button.o:test.c:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `Button_show'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [test] Error 1
```

makefile:

```
LFLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -Wl,-subsystem,windows
CFLAGS = 
SOURCES =test.c Button.c
EXECUTABLE =test

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS)
$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCES)
    gcc $< -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    del /Q *.o *.exe
```

test.c

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "bool.h"
#include "Button.h"

#define TEST_SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define TEST_SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
#define TEST_SCREEN_BPP 32

SDL_Surface *load_image(char* filename);
void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* dest, SDL_Rect* clip);
bool init(SDL_Surface** screen);
bool load_files(SDL_Surface** image);
void clean_up(SDL_Surface* image);

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* buttonSheet = NULL;
    Button* myButton;
    myButton = malloc(Button_size());
    SDL_Event event;

    if(!init(&screen)) return 1;
    bool quit = false;

    if(! (buttonSheet = load_image("button.png")) ) return 1;

    if(!Button_constr(myButton, buttonSheet, 170,120,320,240));

    while(!quit)
    {

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {

            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) quit = true;
            else Button_handleEvents(myButton, &event);

        }

        SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

        Button_show(myButton, screen);

        if(SDL_Flip(screen)) return 1;

    }

    free(myButton);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}



bool init(SDL_Surface** screen)
{

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) return false;

    (*screen) = SDL_SetVideoMode(TEST_SCREEN_WIDTH,TEST_SCREEN_HEIGHT,TEST_SCREEN_BPP,SDL_SWSURFACE);

    if(!(*screen)) return false;

    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Event test", NULL);
    return true;

}

SDL_Surface *load_image(char* filename)
{

    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = IMG_Load(filename);

    if(loadedImage)
    {

        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);

        if(optimizedImage)
        {

            Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(optimizedImage->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF);
            SDL_SetColorKey(optimizedImage, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, colorkey);

        }

    }

    return optimizedImage;


}

void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* dest, SDL_Rect *clip)
{

    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, dest, &offset);

}
```

test.h:

```
#ifndef id250CBE4C_8C40_40EC_B4D7264D6B1E451C
#define id250CBE4C_8C40_40EC_B4D7264D6B1E451C

void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* dest, SDL_Rect* clip);

#endif
```

Button.c:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "Button.h"
#include "test.h"
#include "bool.h"

#define CLIP_MOUSEOVER 0
#define CLIP_MOUSEOUT 1
#define CLIP_MOUSEDOWN 2
#define CLIP_MOUSEUP 3

void Button_PRIVATE_setClips(Button* self);

struct Button
{

    SDL_Rect box;
    SDL_Rect *clip;
    SDL_Surface* image;
    SDL_Rect clips[4];

};

int Button_size()
{

    return sizeof(Button);

}

void Button_PRIVATE_setClips(Button* self)
{

    self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOVER].w = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOUT].w = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEDOWN].w
        = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEUP].w = 320;
    self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOVER].h = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOUT].h = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEDOWN].h
        = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEUP].h = 240;

    self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOVER].x = self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOVER].y = 0;
    self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOUT].x = 320, self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOUT].y = 0;
    self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEDOWN].x = 0, self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEDOWN].y = 240;
    self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEUP].x = 320, self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEUP].y = 240;

}

bool Button_constr(Button* self, SDL_Surface* image, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{

    Button_PRIVATE_setClips(self);

    self->box.x=x;
    self->box.y=y;
    self->box.w=w;
    self->box.h=h;

    self->clip = &self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOUT];

}

void Button_handleEvents(Button* self, SDL_Event* event)
{

    int x=0, y=0;
    SDL_GetMouseState(&x,&y);
    self->clip = &self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOUT];

    if( (x> self->box.x) && (x< self->box.x+self->box.w) 
        && (y> self->box.y) && (y< self->box.y+self->box.h) )
    {

        if(event->type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION) self->clip = &self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEOVER];
        else if(event->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && event->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) 
            self->clip = &self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEDOWN];
        else if(event->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP && event->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
            self->clip = &self->clips[CLIP_MOUSEUP];

    }


}

void Button_show(Button* self, SDL_Surface* screen)
{

    apply_surface( self->box.x, self->box.y, self->image, screen, self->clip);
}
```

Button.h:

```
#ifndef id5CB3FF3A_7168_477D_AAFF0F481C46197C
#define id5CB3FF3A_7168_477D_AAFF0F481C46197C

#include "bool.h"

typedef struct Button Button;
//constructor
bool Button_constr(Button* self, SDL_Surface* image, int x, int y, int w, int h);
int Button_size();
void Button_handleEvents(Button* self, SDL_Event* event);
void Button_show(Button* self, SDL_Surface* screen);

#endif
```

bool.h:

```
#ifndef idF3FFBDD5_86AB_4992_88037678AEADE02B
#define idF3FFBDD5_86AB_4992_88037678AEADE02B

typedef enum{false, true} bool;

#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 2 lines show the error clearly:

```
gcc test.c -c -o test.o
gcc test.c -c -o Button.o
```

You're compiling `test.c` twice.

This is caused by the incorrect use of `$<` in the Makefile. It's meant to be used in pattern rules, like

```
.c.o:
        cc -c $< -o $@
```

or one of the fancier (less portable) GNU pattern rules with `%.o` and `%.c`.

Your `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` is not a pattern rule. It's just a regular rule with some pre-computed filename lists interpolated in it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're including bool.h multiple times. If you include Button.h which includes bool.h then you don't need to include bool.h again like you do in Button.c or test.c. That can cause weird behavior like this.